# Android WebRTC The order of m-lines in answer doesn't match order in offer. Rejecting answer

Tags: android, webrtc

When I use Android WebRTC call FreeSWITCH Error
The order of m-lines in answer doesn't match order in offer. Rejecting answer. (INVALID_PARAMETER).

Follow is call sdp

Why i can't submitted this question?

This is my Offer SDP

```
v=0
o=- 4052293091244096016 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS
m=video 47730 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 125 104
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.229
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:3161858559 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.2.229 47730 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:ScCb
a=ice-pwd:1hsQIC6Z2q6DW3rf5S9ZAO17
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 1F:6C:75:E4:BB:A8:E9:76:A7:03:80:61:F7:31:C1:FC:CB:12:61:00:63:10:82:30:97:4D:53:B6:91:93:84:0B
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=sendrecv
a=msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:127 red/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:125 apt=127
a=rtpmap:104 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 457939972 2191745282
a=ssrc:457939972 cname:24CAMrcezDreoUPY
a=ssrc:457939972 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
a=ssrc:457939972 mslabel:ARDAMS
a=ssrc:457939972 label:ARDAMSv0
a=ssrc:2191745282 cname:24CAMrcezDreoUPY
a=ssrc:2191745282 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
a=ssrc:2191745282 mslabel:ARDAMS
a=ssrc:2191745282 label:ARDAMSv0
m=audio 41823 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 105 13 110 113 126
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.229
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:3161858559 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.2.229 41823 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:ScCb
a=ice-pwd:1hsQIC6Z2q6DW3rf5S9ZAO17
a=ice-options:trickle renomination
a=fingerprint:sha-256 1F:6C:75:E4:BB:A8:E9:76:A7:03:80:61:F7:31:C1:FC:CB:12:61:00:63:10:82:30:97:4D:53:B6:91:93:84:0B
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:2445336154 cname:24CAMrcezDreoUPY
a=ssrc:2445336154 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0
a=ssrc:2445336154 mslabel:ARDAMS
a=ssrc:2445336154 label:ARDAMSa0
```

This is FreeSWITCH Answer Sdp

```
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1524537898 1524537899 IN IP4 114.112.101.159
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 114.112.101.159
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS GfaeNPVcQ4bAnPyGzrcAUcXtNirtkE3R
m=video 30234 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
b=AS:102400
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:2C:4A:1C:DA:70:3F:C2:26:70:CB:19:B3:96:BF:17:F0:46:EB:1A:A6:C1:34:2D:F2:FD:2B:EE:49:62:DA:1E
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:30234 IN IP4 114.112.101.159
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=ssrc:2979419963 cname:K4WoJHqpBsQP7emx
a=ssrc:2979419963 msid:GfaeNPVcQ4bAnPyGzrcAUcXtNirtkE3R v0
a=ssrc:2979419963 mslabel:GfaeNPVcQ4bAnPyGzrcAUcXtNirtkE3R
a=ssrc:2979419963 label:GfaeNPVcQ4bAnPyGzrcAUcXtNirtkE3Rv0
a=ice-ufrag:voXgrLA4TRn3mhLX
a=ice-pwd:bxbL4s1wKHcIMo58DTeUuFPd
a=candidate:9062859322 1 udp 659136 114.112.101.159 30234 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=audio 17628 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 110
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:2C:4A:1C:DA:70:3F:C2:26:70:CB:19:B3:96:BF:17:F0:46:EB:1A:A6:C1:34:2D:F2:FD:2B:EE:49:62:DA:1E
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:17628 IN IP4 114.112.101.159
a=ice-ufrag:N0HFnicpQPELN7uR
a=ice-pwd:SPnxSArP0rneuju891DnaGCQ
a=candidate:0012605909 1 udp 659136 114.112.101.159 17628 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
a=ssrc:3741676838 cname:K4WoJHqpBsQP7emx
a=ssrc:3741676838 msid:GfaeNPVcQ4bAnPyGzrcAUcXtNirtkE3R a0
a=ssrc:3741676838 mslabel:GfaeNPVcQ4bAnPyGzrcAUcXtNirtkE3R
a=ssrc:3741676838 label:GfaeNPVcQ4bAnPyGzrcAUcXtNirtkE3Ra0
```

This is bu for WebRTC ?

What's the matter ?

Comment: (peerconnection.cc:5707): The order of m-lines in answer doesn't match order in offer. Rejecting answer. (INVALID_PARAMETER)

What's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 2):

New WebRTC library generates SDP with some mandatory changes.
In my case were several issues:

1. The order of lines in FREE SWITCH sdp-answer
2. Some lines did not exist in FREE SWITCH sdp-answer

That's why I changed my FREE SWITCH sdp-answer to the answer (new WebRTC library)

Check if your answer contains these lines

```
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=mid:0
a=sendrecv
```

Here is the example of the correct answer

```
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1538507700 1538507701 IN IP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS r79J1Y6SlYKAs3yPp3iawocKYi2MHeLY
m=audio 55748 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 110 106
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/8000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 37:E6:36:30:65:A0:AF:EF:37:C7:36:5E:45:6B:4F:56:AC:EE:50:F5:9A:5F:9A:73:D3:0A:6B:3A:78:F5:30:AE
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:55748 IN IP4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
a=ssrc:1540601138 cname:bKx3yuMJim9Bfyhv
a=ssrc:1540601138 msid:r79J1Y6SlYKAs3yPp3iawocKYi2MHeLY a0
a=ssrc:1540601138 mslabel:r79J1Y6SlYKAs3yPp3iawocKYi2MHeLY
a=ssrc:1540601138 label:r79J1Y6SlYKAs3yPp3iawocKYi2MHeLYa0
a=ice-ufrag:spwPEyptHi5enG3p
a=ice-pwd:hqjFLVfT8ekeDszVHVBckQvS
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the offer sdp

a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
to 
a=group:BUNDLE video audio

and other's 0 to video; 1 to audio;

Answer (score 1):

you can change order of media about audio and video

your sdp is first

Answer (score 1):

SDP describes session configuration including streams settings. Configuration lines related to media configuration (audio, video streams) - are m-lines.

If you OFFER to use 2 media streams `a=group:BUNDLE 0 1`. (`mid:0` and `mid:1`) then ANSWER should also contain 2 same streams so they could be connected.

In your case you have no `group:BUNDLE` instruction and no `mid` stream definitions, which means it is impossible to identify how to connect streams between OFFER and ANSWER.
You second party either incorrectly configured though can't receive streams offered, or uses outdated WebRTC version.

Links to more info about SDP params and structure description:

https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/

https://webrtchacks.com/update-anatomy-webrtc-sdp-anton-roman/

Other incorrect configuration example:

```
OFFER:
....other fields...
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2 3
....
a=mid:0
.....
a=mid:1
.....
a=mid:2
.....
a=mid:3


ANSWER:
....other fields...
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
....
a=mid:0
.....
a=mid:1
```